# Windows 7 Jump-List (Windows Forms, C#)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-7, jump-list

Does anybody know how to customize the Windows Jump-List feature related to my own application in C#? I know it can be done, but I cannot find anything C#/Windows7 related on MSDN yet. The only info related to W7 and C# I can find so far is just compatibility junk which I've already read.

Thanks all
Baeltazor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

There is a sample in Samples\Shell\TaskbarDemo\CS which shows you how to customise the Jump List and icon.